# Accessing properties of Core Data objects via bindings from non-Core Data objects

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have a set of data created by another app and stored in XML format on disk.  Since this data is managed by this other app, I don't want to bother with loading this data into a Core Data store for two reasons: 1) it would be redundant storage of the same data, and 2) I would have to constantly update my own Core Data store to match updates in the XML file produced by the other app.

However, I have data created in my own app that needs to be associated with the data from the XML from the other app, and I want to save the data created in my own app to disk.

To accomplish this, the XML data from the other app has persistent, unique IDs associated with each object stored in the XML file.  I store these unique IDs in my own Core Data store.  Upon every launch of my app, I load the XML data created by the other app, and then I can access the corresponding data in my own app via Core Data by issuing a fetch request for managed objects matching the unique ID.

OtherAppObjects represents items loaded from the XML data.  They have their own unique properties in addition to the uniqueID.  These OtherAppObjects are controlled by an NSArrayController.  Then I have MyManagedObjects which are loaded from the Core Data store, and have distinct unique properties in addition to a uniqueID.

I have a table view which needs to display properties from both the OtherAppObjects as well as the MyManagedObjects, so I want to be able to access and set properties of the MyManagedObjects via bindings from the OtherAppObjects.  Thus, I figured that I could create a correspondingMyManagedObject property of the OtherAppObjects, and then I'd be able to access the Core Data properties of the MyManagedObject via bindings.

For example, if I wanted to display property "foo" of the OtherAppObjects, and "bar" of the MyManagedObjects in the table view, I could simply bind one table column to the NSArrayController with a model key path of "foo", and bind the second table column to the model key path of "correspondingMyManagedObject.bar".

This works when not dealing with multiple threads, or when passing around a single managed object context.  But since that's "strongly discouraged", I wanted to try to do this the right way by passing around a single persistent store coordinator, but creating separate managed object contexts.

However, this breaks down.  The problem is that when the table view attempts to access the bar property, it needs to first access the correspondingMyManagedObject property.  So, the OtherAppObject dutifully creates a new managed object context and a corresponding fetch request with the appropriate uniqueID and returns the managed object.  But in doing so, it releases the managed object context and now the managed object is no longer valid, so the table view can't access the bar property!

I see only two ways around this, and I wanted to verify that there isn't another easier way to do this:

1. Load the objects from the XML data into my own Core Data store.  In essence, create ManagedOtherAppObjects from the OtherAppObjects, with a relationship to the MyManagedObjects, and then accessing via bindings will be peachy.  However, this means there's redundant storage of the same data on disk, *and* I'll have to recreate the ManagedOtherAppObjects every single time I launch the app (because the XML file is updated fairly frequently).
2. Create custom setters/getters on the OtherAppObject class.  So, for example, I'd create `-(NSValue *)bar` and `-(void)setBar:(NSValue *)newValue` methods in OtherAppObject.  Then, instead of binding the table view column to the key value path "correspondingMyManagedObject.bar" of OtherAppObjects, I'd just bind it to the key path "bar" of OtherAppObjects.  These methods would be able to fetch the corresponding MyManagedObject and retrieve or set the value *within* the managed object context, and then return the correct value.

This second method isn't particularly appealing because I'd have to create two custom methods for every single property of MyManagedObject (*and* for properties of *other* managed objects for which MyManagedObject has a relationship).

I suppose I could create the generalized methods `-(NSValue *)retrieveCoreDataPropertyUsingKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath` and `-(void)setCoreDataProperty:(NSValue *)newValue usingKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath` , but I'd still have to create shell setters/getters for each individual property.

[UPDATE: Hmm, maybe I could just override `valueForKeyPath:` and `setValue:forKeyPath:`, and then everything would work OK?]

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One variation on option #1 that could be worth a try would be to set things up so that you have a single persistent store coordinator that splits the objects between two separate persistent stores. You would keep MyManagedObjects (MMO) the same, being stored separately on disk, but then the OtherAppObjects (OAO) could either be backed by some temporary store on disk (e.g. in ~/Library/Caches or something) or just by an in-memory store.

Upon launch, you would create your PSC and add the store containing the MMOs. You would then add a second store to the PSC (using `-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]`), read in the XML file and create all the OAOs, and associate those objects with that store using `-[NSManagedObjectContext assignObject:toPersistentStore:]`.

Core Data doesn't allow directly modeling relationships between objects in different stores, but you could still do the lookup via unique ID like you're doing now to associate a MMO with an OAO. The difference would be that the OAO could simply use its own managed object context to fetch the MMO, so you would be sure that the MMO would stick around at least as long as the OAO.

Then, when you quit the app, you'd either delete the temporary store in ~/Library/Caches, or if using an in-memory store, just let it disappear into the ether, leaving the other store with the MMOs intact.

Comment: This is intriguing idea.  I tried implementing it.  It works as advertised, with one extremely big drawback: performance is unacceptable.

The only way to keep references to managed objects in different stores seems to be via fetch requests.  So now, when I want to access a property of the MMOs via the OAOs (which are themselves now managed objects), I go through the "correspondingMyManagedObject" property of the OAOs, which is simply a fetch request.  Generating thousands of these fetch requests from a table view results in waiting two minutes for app startup, when it was previously 2 seconds

Comment: Hm, occurs to me that I can store a reference to the object via objectID, rather than needing a fetch request... this idea may yet work.

Comment: If you do use objectIDs, watch out for temporary IDs, and make sure only to save permanent ones.